# No application is associated with the specified file for this operation. error

Tags: java

I have tried to open a .jpg file in default program in this way:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File image = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") +         
"/Desktop/project/XL-116/DATAFILE17.jpg");
    try {
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(image);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // .....
    }
}
}
```

And I have got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to open C:\Users\khuda 
Dad\Desktop\project\XL-116\DATAFILE17.jpg. Error message: No application is 
associated with the specified file for this operation.

at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Unknown Source)
at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

[image: Screenshot of program association]

And I have checked the default program. There's nothing wrong. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the fact that the file has an associated application to run, doesn't mean that the "open" operation can be applied.

> No application is associated with the specified file **for this operation**.

<sup>*(Emphasis mine)*</sup>

The action "open" is not applicable. What happens if you right-click on **DATAFILE17.jpg**? It for me it appears as **Edit**. That could be the actual action which is issued.

Of course, it can depend from computer to computer, but my guess is that the action is "**edit**". Try this:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().edit(image);
```

The method `isSupported(Desktop.Action action)` returns whether the action is supported.

Comment: I agree: "IOException - if the specified file has no associated application or the associated application fails to be launched"